# Creating a segue from tableViewController is adding a navigation bar in destination viewController

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

Please see below for the two images, one before adding segue and one after adding segue. Notice the extra navigation bar at the very top of the destination view controller. I do not want that. Why is it being added? How do I remove it, while still maintaining the segue?

**Before segue**
[image: Before segue]

**After segue**
[image: After segue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also another way is to change the way you present the segue. Change kind to: **Present Modally**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This worked. The above two solutions did not work because I still need the original navigation bar to be visible in both controllers as shows in image 'before segue'

Answer (score 0):

Select the controller from interface builder and deselect shownavbar it will stop being visible 
Can try this as well

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select navigation controller and in attribute section check hide navigation bar